# VNC Access to Remote Centos Host from Windows 10

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, centos, vnc

So, I have a CentOs 7 linux box that is running a tigervnc server. I can ping the vncserver_ip_address box from windows. I'm able to connect to the vnc session from another linux box on the same network with the following terminal command:

> vncviewer -RemoteResize=0 -shared localhost:1 -via vncserver_ip_address

I would like to also connect from a windows 10 box.

1. I've tried various ways of starting tigervnc's vncviewer.exe on windows but how do I give vncviewer.exe the -via flag? Is the syntax different in windows?
2. Once it's working, I would like to store all of these switches in a .vnc config file for windows and linux. I've searched online but can't seem to find a template. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

the "via" flag indicates a connection via ssh. On windows it is necessary to use putty or enable the ssh client.

`ssh -L 5902:[vnc host]:5901 [ssh host]`

then:

`vncviewer localhost:2`

More info can be found here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html

And here: https://pureinfotech.com/install-openssh-client-windows-10/

Comment: Do any windows vnc clients handle this implicitly?

Comment: Not that I know